# sphinx - Column count doesn't match

Tags: c, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have the following in my sphinx

```
mysql> desc rec;
+-----------+---------+
| Field     | Type    |
+-----------+---------+
| id        | integer |
| desc      | field   |
| tid       | uint    |
| gid       | uint    |
| no        | uint    |
+-----------+---------+
```

And I ran the following successfully in sphinx sql

```
replace into rec VALUES ('24','test test',1,1, 1 );
```

But when I run in the C mysql API I get this error

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

the c code is this

```
  if (mysql_query(con, "replace into rec VALUES ('24','test test',1,1, 1 )") ) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }
```

Please note that the C program is connecting to the sphinx sql with no issues

Comment: is it escaped characters problem? - do you have to escape the `'`s?

Comment: what version of MySQL are you running?  I have never heard of and can find no documentation for either the "field" or "uint" column types.  Can you post the results of "show create table rec"?

Comment: This is sphinx sql and not mysql one, I'm using C MySQL api to insert into it

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are connecting to sphinx correctly? That is not a sphinx error message.

Comment: The sphinxQL error is more like `ERROR 1064 (42000): column count does not match schema (expected 4, got 5)` - thats from a live server.

Comment: Further to Barry's point - are you connecting to localhost? Or 127.0.0.1? If you use localhost, I think you'll find the port number is ignored and MySQL libraries always connect to MySQL (via the unix socket).

Answer (score 1):

One problem may be that you are quoting the integer for the id column.  I would try taking out the single quotes around the 24.  The column named desc is also concerning, since that is a reserved word in MySQL.

A good best practice is to always specify the column names, even if you are inserting into all columns.  The reason is that you may want to alter the table later to add a column and you don't necessarily want to go back and change all your code to match the new structure.  It also makes your code clearer since you don't have to reference the table structure to know what the values mean and it helps in case a tool like Sphinx is using a different order for the columns than you expect.  Try changing your code to this, which specifies the columns and quotes them (mysql uses backticks for quotes) and also removes the quotes around the value for the id column:

```
if (mysql_query(con, "replace into rec (`id`, `desc`, `tid`, `gid`, `no`) VALUES (24, 'test test', 1, 1, 1)") )
```

Comment: did you escape your single quotes?